# Rest Assured - Send POST Request (Content-Type : multipart/form-data) with Static JSON Payload and Files to be uploaded

Tags: rest-assured

I want to send a POST Request where -

1. Content Type is "multipart / form-data".
2. In "Body" section, I have 2 params -> **body** - {static JSON Payload}, **files** - {any file, say .log file}
   [image]

[image]

In Rest Assured Code, I am able to get the Static JSON Payload in String format with below code -

```
            String jsonFilePath = "<<Path to JSON File>>/Test_new.json";
        String response = given().log().all().header("X-AUTH-TOKEN",res).body(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonFilePath)))).     
                when().post("<<POST RESOURCE URL>>").
            then().log().body().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();
```

When running this code, only with Static JSON Payload, I am getting "415" error code.
**Questions -**

1. How can we successfully make this kind of call in Rest Assured?
2. When I want to upload files as well with this call, how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `multiPart()` methods for uploading files, not `body()` method. For example:

```java
    File json = new File("src/test/resources/test_new.json");
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/debug.log");
    
    given().log().all()
            .multiPart("files", file)
            .multiPart("body", json, "application/json")
            .post("your_url");
```

Comment: @user1865709 please mark it as correct answer and upvote if you can. Thanks